Embedded tomcat 9.x : no content in 404 response
I am using Embedded tomcat 9.0.75 version. When i hit http://localhost:8080/abc URL which is not exist then tomcat is giving 404 HTTP response code with NO content.
As per my previous experience , it should give 404 with content-type as 'text/html' and in content there was a message something like Requested URL is not present
Is there any change in tomcat 9.x with this respect ? or any configuration i need to make ?
